# How to obtain a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I know the question will be marked as duplicate, because I , too, have read couple of similar questions on SO. But unfortunately none of the answers worked for me. I tried all of 'em and as a last option I wanted to ask.

```
void AsyncClass::method1()
{
    cout << "method is called" << endl;
}

void AsyncClass::method2()
{
    auto t = new std::thread(this->method1);
}
```

Both of the methods are public and non-static. This doesn't compile saying

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Also considering the answers on SO I have tried

```
auto t = new std::thread(this->method1);
auto t = new std::thread(this->*method1);
auto t = new std::thread(&(this->method1));
auto t = new std::thread(&AsyncClass::method1);
```

None of them compiled. What is the correct way to to it?

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
auto t = new std::thread(&AsyncClass::method1, this);
```

Comment: It worked. But why? what if **method1** takes parameters? Will **this** be treated as parameter?

Comment: `this` essentially _is_ the hidden, first parameter to (non-static) member functions.

Comment: all non static methods have implicit parameter this (so they know which instance they operate with), all other parameters go after this

Comment: Yes I have tried and it works without problem. I need to wait for 4 minutes in order to accept the answer.